# How do I trigger conditional post processing action without violating SRP?

Tags: java, design, design-patterns, object-oriented-design, solid

I have a `User` Model as below, this Model class is in the shared library.

```
class User {
    private long userId;
    private String email;
    private String userType;
    private long departmentId;

    // ... other fields and getter setters
}
```

In my code, I am persisting User Objects. In order to persist User object, I need to first pull the departmentId by calling an internal microservice and then save it in DB.

```
class UsersUpdateService {

    // Depeendency Injection
    private DepartmentServiceHttpClient departmentServiceClient;
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public void updateUser(User user) {
        long deptId = departmentServiceClient.getDepartment(user.getUserId());
        user.setDepartmentId(deptId);
        userRepository.update(user);
    }
}
```

If you can see `User` has `UserType`, there are around 10 UserTypes available in the system. Now there is a new requirement if a UserType is `SuperUser` I need to send an email to the User after saving the object in DB.

To achieve this, I have created EmailService and I am calling `emailService.sendEmail(user);` after `userRepository.update(user);` line

```
public void sendEmail(User user) {
    if (user.getUserType().equals(UserType.SUPERUSER.name)) {
        //send email
    }
}
```

However, It looks like a hack and not a good design. Also, I think I think I am violating `SRP` by calling `sendEmail(...)` in `updateEmail(...)`. And I think the solution will not scale well in the future, if there are requirements for different UserTypes. Also, I don't think AOP would be a good fit here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to design this in a scalable way is to implement a publisher/subscriber mechanics ( for example, utilizing [java.util.Observer](https://www.baeldung.com/java-observer-pattern), or by utilizing a stored [lambda expression](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_lambda.asp)) in the `UserRepository`. This will allow to send a notification to an observer object (or just call the injected lambda function) whenever the `UserRepository.update` method is called.

The observer can check whether certain conditions are fulfilled (for example, which kind of user was updated), and then call the email sending service.

This avoids any direct coupling between the email service and the user-related classes.

Some scetched code (I am more a C# programmer, hope I got the Java syntax right):

```
 var emailService = new EmailService();
 // ...
 var userRepo = new UserRepository((user)-> emailService.send(user), /* other parameters */);
 // ...
 var userUpdateService=new UserUpdateService(userRepo);

 // and inside UserRepository
 class UserRepository
 {
      Consumer<User> updateCallback;    
      public UserRepository(Consumer<User> uc, /* ...*/)
      {
         updateCallback=uc;
      }
      public void updateUser(User user)
      {
          // code for updating ....
          if(updateCallback!=null)
                updateCallback(user);
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The main point I would raise is that the above is **not OO** at all. Having data structures and procedures (services) is arguably exactly the opposite of OO.

Second, please ignore SRP and SOLID. Because those (with the possible exception of L) are not well enough defined, they can't help you.

Third, coming to the problem at hand, you are using a type marker (userType) instead of *polymorphism*. This is a classic anti-pattern, which in this case derives probably from the `User` "object" being mapped directly to database.

That all being said, the proper solution would probably be *polymorphism*. That is, getting rid of `userType` and having a `SuperUser` class explicitly and implementing its notification logic in there.

Comment: This is a decent answer -- making a hierarchy of `User` subclasses and having each implement `sendEmail`, would also be my first thought -- but the advice to ignore SRP and SOLID is overly harsh, and is probably what is attracting the downvotes.

Comment: @B.Ithica You're probably right. I know it is unpopular thing to be against SOLID. I just want to save some time for the questioner. I do think it'll get you nowhere to try to conform to something that has as many interpretations as readers. Conforming to a bad interpretation is worse than ignoring it altogether.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam Thanks for the inputs, But I cannot modify the `User`  as it's coming from a shared library.

Comment: Honestly, I think from the question it is pretty clear which responsibilties the OP wants to have separated, SRP bashing does not look very constructive.

Comment: @DocBrown Point taken. I will try to tone it down.